# Search for duplicates

Tags: python, django, postgresql, search, duplicates

I have two hundred thousand records in the SQL table. The model has 6 fields. Considered that duplicate is the match of 3 or more fields with any another tuple in this table. I need to find duplicates and their number for each row in this table

Comment: This is very vague description of what you want to do. Could you please add more details about schema and what fields you want to use for finding duplicates ?

Comment: It looks to me that this is actually a bad modeling. Typically if you treat columns that way, these should actually be rows in another table, you basically here look for "pivoting" a database table.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select * from (
select
 n.id as needle_id,
 h.id as haystack_id,
 case when n.a = h.a then 1 else 0 end 
 + case when n.b = h.b then 1 else 0 end 
 + case when n.c = h.c then 1 else 0 end
 + case when n.d = h.d then 1 else 0 end
 + case when n.e = h.e then 1 else 0 end
 + case when n.f = h.f then 1 else 0 end as matching_columns_count
from 
 my_table n
join 
 my_table h 
on 
 n.a = h.a 
 or n.b = h.b
 or n.c = h.c
 or n.d = h.d
 or n.e = h.e
 or n.f = h.f
order by 
 matching_columns_count desc
) z where matching_columns_count >= 3
```

Where `{a,b,c,d,e,f}` are the names of the columns in your table

I doubt this will run quickly